# ASP.NET CMS with Editable Pic Gallery

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, blogengine.net

I have been using BlogEngine for some time as a CMS (Web Forms version). Does anyone know of a plug-in image gallery (need ability to upload, delete, etc.) for BE? Failing that is there, any standalone ASP.NET image gallery out there I could customize and incorporate into BlogEngine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to give this a try - found this in the BE extension gallery:

http://dnbegallery.org/cms/List/Extensions/PrettyPhoto2

http://rtur.net/blog/post/2011/01/04/Picasa-and-PrettyPhoto-updated-for-BlogEngineNET-20.aspx